# PostgreSQL 9.2 - 9.6 upgrade with zero downtime

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I have to upgrade from PostgreSQL 9.2 to 9.6. Following are the challenges that I am facing:

1. Since we have streaming replication setup, and PostgreSQL doesn't support lower to upper version upgrade when in streaming replication mode, when I upgrade the master I have to rebuild the slaves and that takes 3 hours. I don't have that time to spare. At any given time we need one slave and one master available. Is there any other way to upgrade without having to rebuild the slaves, using streaming replication?
2. To build logical replication we thought of using slony but slony has some limitations in that it does not automatically replicate:

   - Changes to large objects (BLOBS)
   - Changes made by DDL commands
   - Changes to users and roles
     ...and our application has continuous create commands. So we cannot use slony.

Please suggest something to avoid slave rebuild and to do upgrade with minimal downtime and one master and one slave ready.

Comment: The same issues that stop you using Slony will stop you using other tools like Bucardo, Londiste, pglogical, etc.

You're going to need to adapt the application, so it doesn't do the continuous creates. And yes, LOBs will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading a database will need downtime on your servers. To minimize the downtime, i would suggest you install the newer version in a new server, create a replication setup on that and dump all data from old instance here, and change server pointing so that application points to new server to connect to database.

Comment: Well, we recently upgraded a 9 TB database from 9.3 to 9.6, using `pg_upgrade`.  It took minutes (on master and slave combined), while taking a dump alone needs more than 3 hours.

Comment: But taking dump doesn't need downtime.

Comment: Absolutely, what I meant (and forgot to add) was that restoring the backup takes more or less the same time as taking it, meaning a few ours downtime in our case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , so what i was doing is upgrading master and rebuilding slave , is this the right procedure

Comment: @dezso Could you please suggest if I follow below steps 
1) create new slave server first with new version 
2) setup replication between master (with old pg version) and slave (with new pg version) 
3) Once all good, remove existing slave.
4)upgrade master with pg_upgrade (which will not require much downtime)
I am not sure if master can replicate to slave which has higher pg version.

Comment: Step 2 won't work. The WAL format is not compatible between major versions, hence the need for `pg_upgrade`.

Comment: If you want near zero downtime when upgrading from 9.2 to 9.6 You want Slony. Your downtime can be measured in seconds. I've done it before, I'll probably do it again. It's a stable, reliable method of replication and one of its primary features is running on different versions of postgresql at the same time.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe , will you be able to share setup steps of slony, also i had few questions 1. how will the postgres come  to know that it doesnt have to stream wal files anymore (as we are using streaming replication) and how will it know that  now slony will do the replication 2.how will i check replication status 3.how to check which ddl's slony was not replicating 4. how to confirm data consistency 5.how can i promote standby using slony

Comment: It's complex enough that I can point you to some resources but you'll have to learn a bit by yourself. http://slony.info/documentation/tutorial.html is the basic tutorial for how to set up slony. As for streaming replication you just drop it, i.e. turn off whatever wal_level you've got to minimal. You can check replication by looking in the .clustername schema that gets created when you setup slony replication. Slony seems really complex at first but once you've set up one cluster it gets progressively easier.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe, i was going through the online docs of SLony , we have to enter each table name when trying to replicate , is there any way where we can have all tables of database replicate without entering table name one by one

Comment: Actually you can use tables keyword with posix regex now. and you don't have to assign an id, it'll do that automagically. That tutorial we written long ago before you could do stuff like that.

Comment: Look up the tables keyword here: http://slony.info/documentation/stmtsetaddtable.html

Comment: ADD SEQUENCES = TRUE will also add any sequences assigned to a table automagically. It's really a lot easier than the tutorial might lead you to believe.

Comment: hello @ScottMarlowe i tried upgrading the postgres version got error could not load library "$libdir/slony1_funcs":
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/slony1_funcs": No such file or directory,i have slony installed on Version 9.2 ,  do we have to upgrade slony too when upgrading DB version

Comment: Wait, is slony working on 9.2 but not 9.6? There should be a slony version (they have to match exactly) for each one. I.e. on my server, I see this from aptitude search slony: postgresql-9.2-slony1-2 and postgresql-9.6-slony1-2 I would need both of them to do this.

Comment: hello @ScottMarlowe, i tried setting up slony but got error ""primary keys generated by slony (serialtables) are no longer supported by slony-I. Please remove serialtablesfrom your config file at /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/slon-tools.pm line 312."" what is the alternative , how can we replicate the table with no primary key

Comment: You have to have primary keys. Look me up on google firstname.lastname@gmail.com and we can work this out. This method is too slow etc.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe, sent an invite on hangout , thanks

Comment: @dezso you have an answer, go for it -- point him to `pg_upgrade` so I can upvote you.